# Does graphene actually remain strong for macroworld engineering?

Tags: material-science, graphene

I heard that people envision strong structural materials made out of graphene, but I heard it may weaken when being stack in layers. Is graphene viable for macroworld structural engineering or is it only suitable for electronics and similar applications?